# Run command after the dropbox is synchronized

Tags: database, windows, service, synchronization, dropbox

Is there any way how to run a command, after the dropbox is syncronized?

Use case (for windows):

1. have service which use data (e.g. database service)
2. want to have some data synchroinzed (not all due the size transfer)
3. you have the task, which do export the db after the db is updated to dropbox file (as the update command file)
4. after the new version is synchronized you want to update with this command file the db on the other computers

Note: only for personal use, so ... not need to solve the conflicts (in unique ids for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do solution not by event, but period task: Check timestamp of the sql file and in case of different version update the db